# Переделываю сайт на Joomla под себя

Tags: html, joomla

Как добраться до index файла? Что бы сделать правки в HTML коде

Comment: Там есть вьюха, ее и копайте.

Comment: Посмотрите видео уроки, или любые уроки вообще, хотя бы начальный уровень

Answer (score 1):

Путь: templetes->ваш шаблон

А вообще, если хотите что-то изменить, сначала переопределяют шаблон.Насколько я помню это находится в админке тут: Расширения->менеджер шаблонов->и там в вашем шаблоне выбираете что вам нужно (например: вывод категории или отображение статьи). Можно конечно сразу в joomle изменять, но это не желательно. После того, как переопределите шаблон, тут: **templetes->ваш шаблон->html** появится переопределенная папка. Например, если хотите переопределить articles, появится папка articles. Заходите туда и правите.

**Советую посмотреть эти уроки:**  [уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWPCFbuKoiA)

Тут все подробно рассказывается.